# SQL database – track user's activity

Tags: sql, database

I have a simple database structure, with models and relations:

**Models:**

1. User
2. Group
3. Activity

**Relations:**

1. User/Group –> User belongs to Group, Group has many Users
2. User/Activity –> User has many Activities, Acitivty belongs to User
3. Group/Activity –> Activity belongs to Group, Group has many Activities

My problem – I want to be able to track number of activities performed in the group by the user within a given period (probably per week, but possibly per day) and I do not know what's the best/ most performant way to achieve this.

Theoretically, I can just perform a query that would count those activities based on the `created_at` date attribute but I assume this is not the most performant way (am I wrong?)

Does anyone know how to properly structure something like this?

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. Do you want total activities a particular user has performed in each group in a day or week? A sample data set with expected output will help you get a solution.

Comment: @Samir Yes! The backend I'm writing imposes limits on user's activity, so e.g. the user can only post 7 times per week (or once a day) within the group.

Comment: I would implement such a rule in application code, not in database metadata.

Comment: @BillKarwin Can you explain a bit more? How would you track the numbers of activities within the given week? I only know when the last activity was created by the user (through `created_at` field in the DB)

Comment: As you said, count them based on the `created_at` datetime attribute. Put an index on the `userid` & `created_at` column of course. That is likely to have satisfactory performance unless your site grows to a very large scale, and if it does that, you'd have to redesign everything anyway.

Comment: This is an app for internal use within a client's company (up to 500 users), so that's unlikely to happen :) Thanks a lot for the input. I would like to accept this as the answer – I was mostly worried about the performance, as this is where I have very little experience in.

Comment: @Ancinek . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2):

As per the relationship provided by you, your `activity` table has a foreign key reference to `user_id` and `group_id`, you can get the count of a user activity under a group in a day.

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.group_id, count(a.user_id)
FROM activity a 
WHERE a.user_id = '123'
AND a.group_id = '1'
AND a.activity_time >= '2019-08-31'
AND a.activity_time < '2019-08-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Create a composite key on `user_id, group_id, activity_time` for faster retrieval if table size increases in the future.

Please note this query is in `MySQL`.